# problems with source command in shell

Tags: linux, shell

Good afternoon I have the following command to run me 'code.sh' file which I pass a parameter '$ 1' the problem is that I want to run a 'code.sh' with 'source' this is my command:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -type f -exec ./code.sh {} \;
```

And I do do well occupied

```
source ./code.sh
```

Comment: Presumably you want to use `source` so that `code.sh` can affect the current shell's environment. Unfortunately, `find` is going to execute the argument to `-exec` in a separate process anyway, so you won't get the effect you want.

Comment: What do you recommend? thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tricky. When you `source` a script you need to do it in the current shell, not in a sub-shell or child process. Executing `source` from `find` won't work because `find` is a child process, and so changes to environment variables will be lost.

It's rather roundabout, but you can use a loop to parse `find`'s output and run the `source` commands directly in the top-level shell (using [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)).

```
while read -d $'\0' fileName; do
    source code.sh "$fileName"
done < <(find . -name "*.txt" -type f -print0)
```

Now what's with `-print0` and `-d $'\0'`, you ask? Using these two flags together is a way of making the script extra safe.<sup>†</sup> File names in UNIX are allowed to contain lots of oddball characters including spaces, tabs, and even newlines. While newlines are rare, they are indeed legal.

`-print0` tells `find` to use NUL characters (`\0`) to separate the file names rather than the default newlines (`\n`). Doing this means file names containing `\n` won't mess up the loop. Using `\0` as a separator works well because `\0` is *not* a legal character in file names.

`-d $'\0'`<sup>‡</sup> does the same thing with `read` on the other side. It tells `read` that lines are delimited with `\0` instead of `\n`.

---

<sub><sup>†</sup> You may have seen this trick before. It's common to write `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` to get the same sort of safety when pairing `find` with `xargs`.</sub>

<sub><sup>‡</sup> If you're wondering about `$'...'`: that's Bash [ANSI-C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) syntax for writing string literals containing escape codes. Dollar sign plus single quotes. You can write `$'\n'` for a newline or `$'\t'` for a tab or `$'\0'` for a NUL.</sub>

Comment: Wowwww! This works great, thank you very much friend! :)

Comment: Serious kindly explain to serving this: `$'\0'`

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to use `find` in this way; it will always execute a command in a separate process, not the current shell. If you are using `bash` 4, there's a simple alternative to using `find`:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.txt; do
    [[ -f $f ]] && source code.sh "$f"
done
```